# ckeditor inline mode is not working in IE,not getting toolbar

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, ckeditor

i have implemented ckeditor to provide admin users  inline editing option to edit the page on the browser itself and then update the content to db.
everything is working fine on all browsers but not on IE.
On IE 9 i am seeing this error on console
**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'groups': object is null or undefined 
ckeditor.js, line 647 character 409**

on IE11 no error is showing but still tollbar not coming.

code is somewhat like this please ignore the typos if found any,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor_new/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>


CKEDITOR.plugins.registered['save'] = {
          init: function (editor) {
             var command = editor.addCommand('save',
             {
                  modes: { wysiwyg: 1, source: 1 },
                  exec: function (editor) { // Add here custom function for the save button
                      var div_id=editor.container.getId();
                      var content=editor.getData();    

                      var request = jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "views/submitcontact.jsp",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {
                                Id : div_id,
                                content : content,

                            },
                            success : function(text) {

                               // Do anything you need to do if save successful

                               alert(text);

                               //ed.setProgressState(false); // cancel showing progress    
                             },       
                            error : function( type, req, o ){     
                                  alert("Save Failed\n Error: " + type + "\n HTTP Status: " + req.status);        
                            }
                      });
                  }
             });
             editor.ui.addButton('Save', { label: 'Save', command: 'save' });
          }
      }

    </script>
```

inside body there is a div like this :

```
 <body>  
    <div class="editable" contenteditable="true" id="contact<%=Sect.getSectionId()%>"> 
                                                            <%=Sect.getHtmlContent().getHtmlContent()%>  

</div>
    </body>
```

any suggestion what is the problem with IE?

and this what is written in the config file that comes along the package

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2014, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'others' },
    //  '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'about' },


    ];
    // Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are

    // not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
    config.removeButtons = 'Blockquote,Link,link,divs,Image,SelectAll,Anchor,CreateDiv,Underline,Subscript,Superscript,Inlinesave,CreatePlaceholder,Table,Outdent,Indent,button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,NumberedList,HorizontalRule';

    config.removePlugins='magicline,stylescombo,format';

    // Set the most common block elements.
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

    // Simplify the dialog windows.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
    config.allowedContent=true;
    //config.extraAllowedContent = 'button(*){*}[*];table(*){*}[*]';

    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;

    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
};
```

Comment: This is just the code to add a plugin. show us the code where you initiate the editor

Comment: @royok i have not added anything else in the jsp code ,i have added the complete standard ckeditor package that comes when we download it on to the server.it has all the default files only , i haven't modified anything there

Comment: sounds like its having trouble with your toolbar config. Comment out the `config.toolbarGroups` part and see if it works

Comment: Well, you have a hanging comma in `data`, and there is another in the config (after `{ name: 'about' }`). IE has (in my experience) not handled those all that well.

Comment: version of ckeditor?

Comment: Is the save override somehow relevant?

Comment: @epascarello version is 4.4.6

Comment: @roryok tried removing the toolbar still not working

Comment: @TiesonT. removed the comma but not working

Comment: @Nenotlep i am using this editor for first time ,this override i found on Google to save the content.